# Android Autocomplete Textview Filtering

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I have an **AutoCompleteTextview** but default filtering is not good for me.

eg: The string **"hum"** should match to Hohum `Plumbing, Humphrey Bogart, and Robert Mitchum`, but currently, it is not happening.

Currently, I am passing ArrayList and creating adapter. Now how can I customize the filtering?

Answer (score 3):

In that case, you have to make your own `runQuery` implementation for the filter attached to your `AutoCompleteTextView`'s adapter.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should take a look at [here](http://www.outofwhatbox.com/blog/2010/11/android-simpler-autocompletetextview-with-simplecursoradapter/)

or create you own custom control 
[here](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/02/08/writing-your-own-autocompletetextview/)